# Sed can not replace when string contains double quotes

Tags: sed, quoting

Output error from the execution of sed command:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unterminated `s' command
```

command file that I am trying to execute:

```
#!/bin/sh

old_version='\"version\": \"0.0.0\"'

year=$(date +%y)
dayOfYear=$(date +%j)

version=$year'.'$dayOfYear'.''3434'
echo $version

filepath="/opt/vsts-agent-linux/_work/5/s/projects/tl-angular-map/package.json"

echo $filepath

replace="s/"$old_version"/"$version"/g"

echo $replace

sed -i -e $replace $filepath
```

The problem is that the string that I am buiding from concatenation is not properly closed because of the double quotes in it.

Comment: The `old_version` variable contents contain literal backslashes: your json data most likely does not. See [3.1.2.2 Single Quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes) in the manual

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `version` is a top-level key in your JSON document, you would update it to the value that you want using `jq` like so:

```bsh
jq --arg patch 3434 \
   '.version |= (now | strftime("%y.%j.") + $patch)' file.json >newfile.json
```

This first sets the internal variable `$patch` to the patch release version on the command line.  It then formats a time-stamp string from the current time using `strftime()` and adds the value of `$patch` on to the end of that string.  This resulting string is then assigned to the `version` key at the top-level of the JSON document, and the resulting document is outputted.

Example:

```bsh
$ cat file.json
{
  "key": "value",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

```bsh
$ jq --arg patch 3434 '.version |= (now | strftime("%y.%j.") + $patch)' file.json
{
  "key": "value",
  "version": "21.292.3434",
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

Would you need to make sure that the old version is *not* updated if it is anything other than exactly `0.0.0`, then instead use

```bsh
jq --arg patch 3434 \
    'select(.version == "0.0.0").version |= (now | strftime("%y.%j.") + $patch)' file.json >newfile.json
```

That is, use `select()` to ensure that the object is only ever updated if its `version` value is `0.0.0`.

An alternative way of formulating this, which may look nicer to some:

```bsh
jq --arg patch 3434 \
    '(now | strftime("%y.%j.") + $patch) as $version |
    select(.version == "0.0.0").version |= $version' file.json >newfile.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding literal quotes into strings doesn't mean that the shell understands those quotes. You want this (note, in bash version 4.2+, printf can be used for date formatting)

```bsh
old_version='"version": "0.0.0"'

# "-1" is a magic value meaning "now"
printf -v year '%(%y)T' -1
printf -v dayOfYear '$(%j)T' -1

version="$year.$dayOfYear.3434"
echo "$version"
# or even without the temp variables:
# printf -v version '%(%y)T.%(%j)T.3434' -1 -1

filepath="/opt/vsts-agent-linux/_work/5/s/projects/tl-angular-map/package.json"
echo "$filepath"

replace="s/$old_version/$version/g"
echo "$replace"

sed -i -e "$replace" "$filepath"
```

However, this will replace the string `"version": "0.0.0"` with `21.292.3434`, breaking your JSON object in the file.

```bsh
$ cat package.json
{
  "key": "value",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "foo": "bar"
}

$ sed "s/$old_version/$version/g" package.json
{
  "key": "value",
  21.292.3434,
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

What you should be using to manipulate JSON data is [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) to set the new value:

```bsh
$ jq --arg newversion "$version" '.version = $newversion' package.json
{
  "key": "value",
  "version": "21.292.3434",
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Although I still can't understand how to escape the double quotes in my string, to properly compose sed command

Comment: jq does the job!

Comment: You don't need to escape any quotes in the string. You just need to make sure the variables are quoted when you use them. As I demonstrate in my answer.